# Serving files from war file

Tags: java, servlets, jetty, guice

I am using a java servlet container, which serves files from the webapp directory. Say for instance I have Foo.html. host:80/Foo.html will serve this file. How do I serve the Foo.html for host:80/XXX/YYY, where XXX and YYY may be a number of things? I don't mean a redirect though.

Not sure how important it is. I am using Jetty and Guice filters.

Answer (score 2):

Map a servlet on the desired URL pattern which uses [`RequestDispatcher#forward()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#forward%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29) to forward to the target resource.

```
// ...
request.getRequestDispatcher("Foo.html").forward(request, response);
```

This does not reflect any change in the browser address bar like as a redirect does -if that's your *actual* concern after all. A redirect basically tells the browser to send a brand new HTTP request on the given location. A forward basically tells the servletcontainer to load the given resource in the response.